# Checkbox refuses to be checked or unchecked on highchart

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, highcharts

I am working on a Chart, my goal is to be able to hide or show values on chart, and I have achieved that goal, but unfortunately my checkbox is not unchecked when I hide values or checked when I show them. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.
Anyone have any suggestions ?
I am quite sure there is no need to manipulate dom due fact that highcharts in vast library that probably has something for this specific situation.

This is my jsfiddle on which I was working on

`

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {

            renderTo: 'container',

            type: 'line',

            marginRight: 130,

            marginBottom: 25

        },
        plotOptions: {
                series: {
                                 dataLabels: {
                                         enabled: true
                            }
                         },
            line: {

            events: {
                checkboxClick: function (event){

                 if(event.checked)
                                {

                                 var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                    this.update({
                        dataLabels:{
                            enabled: enabled
                        }
                    });

               return false; 
                                }
                            else{
                                 var a = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                    this.update({
                        dataLabels:{
                            enabled: a
                        }
                    });

               return true; 
                                }

                    },


            },
            showInLegend: true,
           showCheckbox: true
         }
        },                
        title: {

            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',

            x: -20 //center

        },

        subtitle: {

            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',

            x: -20

        },

        xAxis: {

            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',

                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

        },

        yAxis: {

            title: {

                text: 'Temperature (°C)'

            },

            plotLines: [{

                value: 0,

                width: 1,

                color: '#808080'

            }]

        },

        tooltip: {

            formatter: function() {

                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+

                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';

            }

        },

        legend: {

            layout: 'vertical',

            align: 'right',

            verticalAlign: 'top',

            x: -10,

            y: 100,

            borderWidth: 0

        },


        series: [{

            name: 'Tokyo',

            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }, {

            name: 'New York',

            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]

        }, {

            name: 'Berlin',

            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]

        }, {

            name: 'London',

            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]

        }]

    });

});

});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LDMAQ/1088/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: Set dataLabels enabled to false. Now the data won't be shown on start. (this is optional)

```
  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
```

Secondly: Enable the labels if the checkbox is checked by setting enabled to true: `enabled: true`. Make sure to return true if the checkbox is checked. If the the checkbox is unchecked set enabled to false and return false.

```
events: {
        checkboxClick: function(event) {

            if (event.checked) {
                var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                this.update({
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });

                return true;
            } else {
                var a = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                this.update({
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }

        },
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LDMAQ/1095/

Comment: The force within you sir is too stronk for one man to contain, thank you so much.

Comment: Another question if I may Daniel, I tried to make one of those checkboxes checked upon rendering to literally set the value to true of first serie like this
this.chart =  new Highcharts.Chart(chartConf);
this.chart.widgetData = widgetData;
this.chart.series[0].selected = true;
but even if value is true first serie is not checked nor displayed, do you have any idea how can that be done because if it is done through velocity it stays hardcoded for good. Thank you !

Comment: Yes you can do this by adding `selected: true,
                dataLabels: {
                 enabled: true
                },` to one of your series. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LDMAQ/1125/

Comment: great stuff, thanks Daniel you are a Jedi, or Sith, whatever you like more.